# jQuery prettyPhoto issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, modal-dialog, syntax-error, prettyphoto

I am trying to implement the jQuery plugin, prettyPhoto, on my page. I used the example from this page:

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#!prettyPhoto

When I use the `rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"` I get an error message about wrong syntax:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: `[rel*=[pp_gal]`

What can be the issue?

I have installed the prettyPhoto jQuery plugin in my project. I have put this script in 
the page:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
      $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
 });
```

And I used this HTML in order to see the images, the path is localhost since I am trying just to make it work for now:

```
<a href="../GalleryImages/ScreenClip[1].png" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img src="../GalleryImages/ScreenClip[1].png" width="60px" height="60px" alt="Nice building" /></a>

<a href="../GalleryImages/1.jpg" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]"><img src="../GalleryImages/1.jpg" width="60px" height="60px" alt="Nice building" /></a>
```

Comment: **How could anyone possibly be able to assist without seeing any of your code?**  See:  http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: IMO, the error is as if you don't have jQuery or the plugin properly included.  Did you include jQuery _before_ the prettyPhoto plugin?  Are you then invoking `.prettyPhoto()` _after_ that? They seem like obvious questions but nobody can see that part of your code.  It's almost like you did not read the link in my first comment.

Comment: yes, the JQuery function is before the link tags. i have acted according to the instructions on the developer site. this isn't something i have decided to do on my own, furthermore i have posted a question about it also in the dedicated forum, but i didn't get any answers.

Comment: prettyPhoto works fine on my site.  But with what little you've posted, we're at a stalemate.

Comment: that's all i have included on my page, according to the developer's site that's all i need to do.
if i try to apply the setting for a single image it works great, but for some reason the gallery option doesn't work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7224/discussion-between-moran-monovich-and-sparky672)

Comment: It's up to you to post enough information so people can answer.  The purpose of this site is to also help anyone else reading your post... at this point, it makes no sense and helps nobody.  Again, please post a link to your page or put up a demo page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the error is related with PrettyPhoto 2.5.x and jQuery 1.3.2 - that version of prettyphoto does not work with newer versions of jQuery.

So if you want prettyPhoto 2.5.x to work, you have to use jQuery 1.3.2.